# $\sin (\frac{\pi}{4n}) \ge \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, contest-math

I have found this weird inequality in a mathematical magazine. $$\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right) \ge \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2n}, n\in \mathbb{N}$$

I tried using induction, but couldn't continue. Then, using the double angle formula, I managed to get an equivalent inequality: $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right) \le 1-\frac{1}{n^2}$ and tried proving it with induction, but, again, it couldn't do it.

Could you help me? I am not very good with trigonometric inequalities...

Comment: Show that $$
n\sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{{4n}}} \right)
$$ is a monotonically increasing sequence.

Comment: I am failing in doing that. Could you sketch a proof please? Also, it would be quite nice if you did not use Calculus as I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\sin$ is a concave function on $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$, because $\forall x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{4}], sin’’(x)=-sin(x) \leq 0$. Therefore, the function is above all its chords, and, in particular, above the one that goes through the points $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$. Hence:

$$\forall x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{4}], \sin x \geq \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{\pi} x$$

The conclusion follows.

Comment: Here's the [graph](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVi0EOwiAQRfecYsJqpqLVxi138ArQNkoCjAJJ4fZOd_-9vO_AwjfADE_lZdZfabiQ8KLGySGjmzrBFfzUVRLlVq7oZ3dGTr3Of-SGwwDeDTyIxF1EcsgNMRkY2G0iMrBy5GJ12Tct0a1--MB3CVsMea9Wp5C5aPoDxy0oMw==&lang=sage) of $$y=\sin\left(\frac\pi4x\right)-\frac{\sqrt2}2x$$